# ngForm controls doesnt change when a variable changes in my class

Tags: angular, typescript

in my angular project , i have a form , and the controls are conditional ,

based on an enum

```
export enum ApplicationPersonalityType {
  Real = 1,
  Legal = 2,
  GovOrganization = 3,
}
```

there are serveral formControls in my NgFrom

and the controls are condditional :

```
<ng-container *ngIf="applicationPersonalityType === ApplicationPersonalityType.Real">
              <tp-float
                [label]="'UI::Start:Applications:Create:ContractInformation:FullName'"
                class="px-2 col-4"
              >
                <input
                  pInputText
                  [required]="true"
                  name="FullName"
                  class="col-12 px-md-4 tp-rounded-2"
                  disabled
                  ngModel
                />
              </tp-float>
<ng-container


ng-container *ngIf="applicationPersonalityType === ApplicationPersonalityType.Legal">
 <tp-float
                [label]="'UI::Start:Applications:Create:ContractInformation:CompanyFullName'"
                class="px-2 col-3"
              >
                <input
                  pInputText
                  [required]="true"
                  name="CompanyFullName"
                  class="col-12 px-md-3 tp-rounded-2"
                  ngModel
                />
              </tp-float>
</ng-container>
```

when the applicationPersonalityType changes in

```
<p-selectButton
          name="SelectedPersonality"
          styleClass="d-md-flex justify-content-center align-items-center p-3 w-100"
          [options]="PersonalityOptions"
          optionValue="value"
          (ngModelChange)="selectPersonality($event)"
          ngModel
        >
        </p-selectButton>
```

the view changes , but the NgForm controls does not.

also here is the ngModelChange event method :

```
selectPersonality(type) {
    if (!type) {
      return;
    }
    this.applicationPersonalityType = type;
    if (this.startUser) {
      if (this.form.controls) {
        switch (type) {
          case ApplicationPersonalityType.Legal:
            this.form.controls.ProxyFullName.setValue(
              `${this.startUser.name} ${this.startUser.family}`
            );
            this.form.controls.ProxyNationalCode.setValue(this.startUser.nationalCode);
            this.form.controls.ProxyPhone.setValue(this.startUser.mobile);
            //TODO When Authorization Service implemented
            //  this.form.controls.ProxyPost.setValue(this.startUser.proxyPost);
            //  this.form.controls.ProxyAddress.setValue(this.startUser.proxyAddress);
            break;
          case ApplicationPersonalityType.GovOrganization:
            break;
          default:
            this.form.controls.FullName.setValue(`${this.startUser.name} ${this.startUser.family}`);
            this.form.controls.NationalCode.setValue(this.startUser.nationalCode);
            break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

where am i going wrong?

Comment: what exactly is not changing? value in `<p-selectButton>` or value in `this.form.controls` ?

Comment: not the values , the whole controls ,

Comment: you mean everything that you changing in switch? e.g.`this.form.controls.ProxyNationalCode` , `this.form.controls.ProxyPhone` etc?

Comment: exactly , im changing `applicationPersonalityType`.
and the controls must change, it does not happen . when i  change the `applicationPersonalityType` the controls are the previous one

Comment: are you sure that conditions are met? try `console.log` something after `if (this.form.controls) {` to assure that switch is executed

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any answers related, I came up with this solution where I define a variable called `SelectedPersonality` and referring to the `SelectedPersonality` ngModel in view:

```
<p-selectButton
          name="SelectedPersonality"
          styleClass="d-md-flex justify-content-center align-items-center p-3 w-100"
          [options]="PersonalityOptions"
          optionValue="value"
          #SelectedPersonality="ngModel"
          ngModel
        >
</p-selectButton>
```

I then subscribed to the value changes in my class, call the `selectPersonality()` method manually:

```
this.SelectedPersonality.valueChanges.subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.selectPersonality(res)
})
```

and change the `selectPersonality()` method a bit :

```
selectPersonality(type) {
    if (!type) {
      return;
    }
    this.applicationPersonalityType = type;
    if (this.startUser) {
      if (this.form.controls) {
       setTimeout(()=>{
        switch (type) {
          case ApplicationPersonalityType.Legal:
            this.form.controls.ProxyFullName.setValue(
              `${this.startUser.name} ${this.startUser.family}`
            );
            this.form.controls.ProxyNationalCode.setValue(this.startUser.nationalCode);
            this.form.controls.ProxyPhone.setValue(this.startUser.mobile);
            //TODO When Authorization Service implemented
            //  this.form.controls.ProxyPost.setValue(this.startUser.proxyPost);
            //  this.form.controls.ProxyAddress.setValue(this.startUser.proxyAddress);
            break;
          case ApplicationPersonalityType.GovOrganization:
            break;
          default:
            this.form.controls.FullName.setValue(`${this.startUser.name} ${this.startUser.family}`);
            this.form.controls.NationalCode.setValue(this.startUser.nationalCode);
            break;
        }
       },1000)
      }
    }
  }
```

In this way, after the timeout, I have access to the new formControls

Comment: not to mention the timeout miliseconds should not be that long  , it would be better to be like 10 ms